# what 's the difference in python if a class sub child object or not?

Tags: python, object

If I write this, the **new** method will not be called

```
class MyClass:
    @classmethod
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print "here"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = MyClass()
```

but when i write like this, the **new** method will be called when calling MyClass
what's the mainly difference when a class sub child object or not?

```
class MyClass(object):
    @classmethod
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print "here"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = MyClass()
```

Comment: You can google "python new style class" for more info.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python